Are there new developments to import pmml Models in R?
My question is basically an update / different specific scenario to this one: Can PMML models be read in R?
Is it possible to import models sepcified as pmml xml files in R? Specifically a CHAID decision tree exported from SPSS Modeler?
The linked question points to some solutions like the partykit package, which apparently is able to import some models, but not the one in question here. In my specifc case I get the error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : CompoundPredicate not yet implemented", which lead to the question if there are any other solutions.
Are there any other new developments that might help in this regard and allow me to import pmml models with CompoundPredicate in the xml?

What is the purpose of importing PMML decision tree models into R? Making predictions, visualization, something else?
For prediction, you may check out the JPMML-Evaluator-R package.

In this case I would use it in a project beeing transfered form SPSS modeler to R with the intention of having the exact same model available in both tools to make predictions. For the future I will anyway create new models in R, but for speed and evaluation reasons this would have been very helpful. I came to the conclusion, that it is not possible to import pmml models with CompoundPredicate structures into R.
I will check out JPMML if it can solve my needs. Thanks for the tip.

Update: The JPMML-Evaluator-R package indeed is able to read in pmml files with "CompoundPredicate" into R and make predictions. Since, it is a thin wrapper around the Java pipeline everything is stored and done within java and not R itself, therefore it is unfortunately not usable in production for my usecase.
But overall it works quite nice!
Note: One should use small java version numbers like 8 or 11.
